# Parent with nested item also triggers child item

Tags: javascript, jquery-ui

I have this sortable item list using jQuery UI Sortable, which is also able to nest items.

Each of these items contains toggable content, it will slide down when clicking on an item.

However, when clicking on the parent item when nested, instead of only toggling the parent content it's also toggling the child's content.

I've been trying to figure it out in my Jquery script but haven't been able to figure it out. I reproduced my issue in this fiddle:

https://jsfiddle.net/es3hbdnm/33/

Also HTML:

```
<ol class="sortable panel-group">
  <li class="panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">Home</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>

  <li class="panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">About us</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>

  <li class="panel-default">
    <div class="toggle">Contact</div>
    <div class="panel-content">Hidden content</div>
  </li>
</ol>
```

My JS:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

  $('.sortable').nestedSortable({
    handle: 'div',
    items: 'li',
    toleranceElement: '> div'
  });


  $(".panel-default").click(function ( event ) {
    event.stopImmediatePropagation();
    $(".panel-content").not($(this)).slideUp();

    $(this).find(".panel-content").slideDown();
  });

});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should slideDown only the first '.panel-content' found.

```
  $(".panel-default").click(function (event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    event.stopPropagation();
    $(".panel-content").not($(this)).slideUp();

    $(this).find(".panel-content:first:hidden").slideDown();
  });
```

Comment: Do you maybe also know how to disable the click function on content within the .panel-content? Like I have a select box inside of it, but when I try to choose a selection, it toggles back up..

Comment: `$('.panel-content').click(function(event){
 event.preventDefault();
  event.stopPropagation();
});`

Add it to your code.

Comment: Thank you, you're my saviour.

Comment: Look, have you seen that when a parent is opened and you try to close it, it closes but then opens again ?

Comment: I edited my response, to solve it too. If it was useful for you, vote up the response, to mark the question as responded.

Answer (score 0):

Note, `.find()` returns a list of descendants of each element in the current set of matched elements. So in case the parent item is clicked the list will also include the child item. Reducing the set of matched elements to the first in the set should do the trick.

```
    $(this).find(".panel-content").first().slideDown();
```

EDIT: Besides this, my suggestion is to use the following to be able to slide up a previously slided down element. See also my updated fiddle. Note, the selector you have provided to `.not` does not match as`this`is a ".panel-default" node rather than a ".panel-content" node.

```
$(".panel-content").not($(".panel-content:first", this)).slideUp();
```

[jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/WittigMarcus/vs3c9tdL/)

Comment: Welcome. Btw, calling .preventDefault() in the first answer is not really required. Besides this my suggested solution is equivalent while using the `:first` selector is presumably more efficient.